Meaning of symbol in PyDev debugger window
I am familiarizing myself with Eclipse and the PyDev plugin. I am learning how to debug a very large application with which I am unfamiliar at present. I am able to run a debug session successfully, but am having difficulty understanding one of the symbols that appears in the debug window after traversing a path through the application. Here is the Eclipse window for reference.

As is evident from this image, the symbol immediately above the one highlighted in dark green in the debug window to the left of the Eclipse window contains two gears at a diagonal angle with the word "salt-minion" to the right. If I click on the arrow to the immediate left of the gears, the arrow disappears. salt-minion is a script shown in the source window in the middle of the Eclipse window. If I continue to debug the application by providing it input, more of these diagonal gear lines appear with the same properties.
Can someone tell me what these lines represent?
